# Users reaction to integrating Flurry

Tags: android, flurry

I'm considering integrating Flurry in my Android App. I have the technical part covered and it's quite easy to use the SDK.
My question is more on the user reaction to integrating such tool into your app. I imagine that some users will not like the fact that there is some kind of tracking\analytics mechanism within the app.
Besides providing an option to stop tracking/logging data inside my app, are there any additional measures you can recommend ?
How would you refer to it on your app description (if at all ?) ?
Is there some standard privacy policy I can use to refer my users to ?

Comment: keep event logging transparent from user. its ethical to not log private user data in your app. FLurry is to log action events, how many users have opened a particular component of you application

Comment: Flurry analytic tracking is anonymous, an event logged cannot be tracked back to a user (at least that's what Flurry claimed, I can't prove or disprove this). I just add an entry in my app's EULA or privacy statement claiming: 'We may track the usage of this app, blah blah blah'.

Comment: Thanks. @azgolfer, do you have any sample privacy policy I can use ?

Comment: in case someone would be interested in creating a privacy policy, I just found the following template: http://www.mmaglobal.com/whitepaper-request?filename=MMA_Mobile_Application_Privacy_Policy_18Oct2011.pdf